# backdrop-filter: blur; not fill all page

Tags: html

On my "body" tag, I put a background image and I wanted to make some blur on it, except that, when we scroll, the blur is disabled

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px) grayscale(25%);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px) grayscale(25%);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";

}

body:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: .6;
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCmCT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I just had to do this :

Before :

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

After :

```
html, body {
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}
```